# Custom validation for input text to validate minimum 2 lowercase characters, 2 uppercase characters, 2 integers and 2 special symbols In Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, html

```
<input ng-pattern="/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])/" name="text" type="text" ng-model="formData">
```

From this I can check minimum 1 lowercase character, 1 uppercase character, 1 integer and 1 special symbol. 
But I want to validate 2 lowercase characters, dynamically minimum numbers will change. So I have to write common validation.
How can I do this?
Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the ranges for each of the rules, e.g. what is the minimum and maximum number of lowercase letters required?

Comment: Minimum number of letters only required. maximum is not limited.

Comment: Could you do this check in your JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

use this for 2 lowercase, 2 uppercase, 2 integer, 2 special character

```
(?=.*[a-z]{1,2})(?=.*[A-Z]{2,2})(?=.*\d{2,2})(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]{2,2})
```

try it [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. The above expression is taking values in ordered way i.e first 2 lower case, then 2 upper case etc. But I dont want to match in an ordered way.